# Using label, and button inside a grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the first column, is it possible to have a label instead a button? Visually I want the same as a label or a button, but I don't wanna it to be clickable. The text is getting out too. And I was trying to make the button smaller but it isn't accepting `width`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ETe8V/show)

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span>AA</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Text</label>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                            <a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla laoreet eget neque</a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">BUTTON</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Text 2</label>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">BUTTON 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide JSFiddel source link as well.

Comment: I did it since the beginning. Between the text and the source. Thanks.

Comment: you fiddle only shows the output in full screen but now way to see the edit option.

Comment: just cut the `/show` part in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visually I want the same as a label or a button, but I don't wanna it
>   to be clickable.

The best way would be to add the disabled attribute on the element. Then cancel out the reduced opacity using your own class

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning myClass btn-sm" disabled>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla laoreet eget neque</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.myClass[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

> The text is getting out too.

Just add this to the above CSS ruleset

```
white-space: normal;
```

---

> And I was trying to make the button smaller but it isn't accepting
>   width.

The display for btn in the btn-group-justified class is table-cell and the width is set to 1% for all columns. So you have to set your width keeping in mind that 1% is the default.

For example the following makes it 25% for a 2 column button group

```
width: 0.5%;
```

---

The complete CSS would be

```
.myClass[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 0.5%;
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wr78t8ug/